# Get bg jobs to fg after closing terminal window/session

Tags: terminal, background-process, jobs, background-foreground

TL;DR How can I get a `bg` (background) job into `fg` (foreground) after I close the terminal window?

FULL I'm using terminal to start Spotify and put it into background with `CTRL+Z` and `bg`. Everything works as expected within this window: `fg` puts the process again in forground and `jobs` shows me Spotify as a running process. The problem occurs if I close the terminal window.

After I close the terminal window and open a new terminal window, the `jobs` command can't find Spotify running in the background. Therefore I can't access the process for stopping or closing anymore.

What is the advantage of this behaviour `CTRL+Z`, `fg`, `bg` & `jobs` ? And how can I get back my process?

Answer (score 6):

You can search your old process via `ps -A`. Or `ps -A | grep <application name>`. 
If you found it, then use `reptyr <pid>` to get the application on your new console.
But if you closed the old terminal, all the terminal applications will probably be closed also, so it's too late.

Use [screen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen), before you start your app. This will help you to reconnect to your session from another terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The job numbers only refer to background processes running under your current shell. The shell couldn't know the job numbers associated with the old shell.